# Browser version 0.0 in visitor logs

Tags: intrusion

I am seeing quite a few browser "version 0.0" in visitor log. Can anyone explain the significance of this? Please see examples below. Thanks.

```
Safari version 0.0 running on ChromeOS
Chrome version 0.0 running on Win8.1
Chrome version 0.0 running on Win7
Chrome version 0.0 running on WinXP
Google Web Preview version 0.0
AppEngine-Google version 0.0
Google Feedfetcher version 0.0
BingPreview version 0.0
WinHttp version 0.0
```

Comment: A guess - your visitor log defaults to version 0.0 when the client do not announce its version

Comment: I think your script fails to parse the version properly, and stores it as a float value; hence the default 0.0.

Comment: A similar question was raised in SO.
Link [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478181/net-4-0-website-cannot-identify-some-applewebkit-based-browsers

Comment: ovtorne - the question dozer linked to should have your answer. The question is off topic here, in any case.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I don't think simply holding the question was an adequate deed, IMHO initiating a migration hadn't been so destrutive.